# Lua Equal To issue in Corona

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm currently developing an android app and I'm having an issue with corona not registering that `fish1` is at `display.contentWidth/3 + 20`. When `fish1` is at `display.contentWidth/3 + 20` then a `newBubble` is made and it appears on the x axis where the fish is.

```
bubbleDivision = display.contentWidth/3 -- How many times the Bubbles will appear
print (bubbleDivision)

if fish1.x == display.contentWidth/3 + 20 then
    newBubble = display.newImage("testBubble.png")
    print "Spawned"

    newBubble.x = fish1.x       
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it is a floating point error. Use `math.floor` or `math.ceil`, whichever is applicable/suitable.

```
bubbleDivision = math.floor( display.contentWidth / 3 )
if math.floor(fish1.x) == bubbleDivision + 20 then
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work. I tried adding it but nothing worked after that